# Pyinstaller error: no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to make my discord bot a .exe file. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olwgk.png) is the directory

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Suneel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 672, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Suneel\Desktop\Programmes on Python\Tic Tac Toe Bot\Tic_Tac_Toe_Bot.spec", line 30, in <module>
    coll = COLLECT(exe,
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 709, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 753, in assemble
    shutil.copy(fnm, tofnm)
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 418, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "c:\users\suneel\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Suneel\\AppData\\Roaming\\pyinstaller\\bincache00_py3
```

And the command i ran:

```
pyinstaller --icon=647618.ico Tic_Tac_Toe_Bot.py
```

I have used Pyinstaller before and it was working perfectly.

Comment: Can you try re-running with a clean build environment? E.g. deleting any files that may have been produced by past runs of pyinstaller?

Comment: oh it worked. At first i you said to create a virtual environment ty!